# Issues with accessing files in a React Native project and storing paths

Tags: typescript, react-native

maybe I also have some basic logical errors. But maybe this will be clarified by answering this question: I created a project folder with React Native, where I created a folder called 'testImages' and placed a few images there. When I start the app and access them using a View component and 'require', it works. So far so good. However, I want to store the image paths in a list and access them later, for example, to save the images using RNFS. But then the path is always undefined. Is there a special project structure for the images? Let's say I don't have any images to display, only PDFs inside. And I want to send the PDFs via email. Then I have nothing to display, but it should still be possible to access the files from the project folder, right?

My example List:

```
export const ImagesAssets3: { [key: string]: string } = {
bannerList1: '/../StandardImages/standard-01.jpg',
bannerList2: '/../StandardImages/standard-02.jpg',
bannerList3: '/../StandardImages/standard-03.jpg',
};
```

and for loop:

```
export async function test() {
  for (const key in ImagesAssets) {
    if (ImagesAssets.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     <Image source={ImagesAssets[key]}></Image>
     const targetPath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/' + ImagesAssets[key].uri + '.jpg';

     console.log("Before save "+ targetPath);
     await RNFS.copyFile(ImagesAssets[key].uri, targetPath);
     console.log("File saved to: " + targetPath +" from " + ImagesAssets[key].uri);
    }
  }
}
```

and Log:

```
 LOG  Before save /data/user/0/com.motimastery/files/undefined.jpg
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
```

So there is "undefinded" and not the uri. (in View-Component i can use it, and Image will be displayed)